# The first if condition is always true

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, discord.py

I'm recently coding a bot for a small server between friends. I'm trying to add a quiz minigame to the bot, but ran into a problem.

Here's the code I have:

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['popquiz', 'trivia'])
async def quiz(ctx, *, arg):
    if arg == 'league':
        QA = leagueQA
    else:
        await ctx.send('The quiz you asked for is not yet available.')
        return
    
    Q = random.randrange(len(QA))
    await ctx.send(QA[Q][0])

    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel
    
    answer = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=20)
    print(answer.content.lower())


    if (substring in answer.content.lower() for substring in QA[Q][1]):
        await ctx.send('Close but not quite.')
        return
    elif (substring in answer.content.lower() for substring in QA[Q][2]):
        await ctx.send('Correct!')
        return
    else:
        await ctx.send('Incorrect')
        return
```

leagueQA is essentially a nested list in the following format:

```
    leagueQA = [
    ['Question 1', ['close answer1', 'close answer2'], ['right answer']],
    ['Question 2', ['close answer1', 'close answer2'],['right answer1','right answer2']],
    ['Question 3', ['close answer'], ['right answer']]]
```

Now when I run the bot and type in $quiz league, the bot will ask me a random question from the list, and when I answer the question, no matter what I say, it will respond with the first response: Close but not quite.

I tried printing the answer to make sure it does take in the correct answer. I've double-checked my nested list and it seems fine. I've tried many different questions and responses, and the results are all the same. Even with a completely wrong answer like 'fadsfcasjdl' the first if condition is still true. I've also tried using substring == answer.content.lower(), using **contains**, and removing the returns, nothing seems to work. Pls send help.

Comment: `(substring in answer.content.lower() for substring in QA[Q][1])` is a generator expression. It will always be truthy. Do you mean to check if *all* substrings are in the answer of if *any* of those substrings is in the answer?

Comment: Can you re-write your [mre] so that the `@bot...` and asyncio is not needed? - Make it as simple as possible but still illustrate the problem.

Comment: Since this is most likely a discord bot, why don't you just use a subcommand / groups?  It seems pretty pointless have *, args which consumes the entire string after it if all you want is something along the lines of $quiz league

You could then have $quiz league, $quiz general etc. without having to to duplicate a lot of code.

Comment: To build on @wwii's comment: Remove all arguments to `quiz()`. Hardcode `QA = ...`. Use `print()` to write to the console, and `input()` to get inputs. You need to create a [mre] so that people won't have to create an entire discord bot just to test your code.

Comment: You clearly expect `(substring in answer.content.lower() for substring in QA[Q][1])` to resolve to `True` or `False`. It doesn't. Try `any(substring in answer.content.lower() for substring in QA[Q][1])` or `all(substring in answer.content.lower() for substring in QA[Q][1])` depending on what you mean.

Comment: I think a dict would be a better data format.  `{"question": {"close answers": [...], "correct answers": [...]})`

Answer (score 3):

You have to check `any` of the tuple.

A non empty tuple is `True` even if it contains `False`.

Try it out:

```
> bool((False))
True
> bool((True))
True
> bool(())
False
```

So you need to change to:

```
    if any(substring in answer.content.lower() for substring in QA[Q][1]):
        await ctx.send('Close but not quite.')
        return
    elif any(substring in answer.content.lower() for substring in QA[Q][2]):
        await ctx.send('Correct!')
        return
    else:
        await ctx.send('Incorrect')
        return
```

You can then adjust for exact or partial matches if you want.